# How to get token from Blackbaud with Ruby GEM oAuth2

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, blackbaud

I'm getting "ERROR: The request could not be satisfied "
I have a ticket with Blackbaud but its taking several days.  Maybe someone out there has done this before and can I identify what I might be doing wrong?

Here's my Ruby code with params replaced by "my_" etc.

```
require 'net/http'
#require 'uri'
require 'oauth2'
# SOURCES: 
# https://gitlab.com/oauth-xx/oauth2/-/blob/main/README.md
# https://developer.blackbaud.com/skyapi/docs/authorization

# SET Params
client_id = 'my_client_id'
client_secret = 'my_client_secret'
site_path = 'https://app.blackbaud.com' 
auth_path = '/oauth/authorize/'
redirect_uri = 'https://my_server.com/bb_oac'

puts 'sending oauth request...\n'

# Relative authorize_url and token_url (Not on site root)
client = OAuth2::Client.new(client_id, client_secret, site: site_path, content_type: 'application/json')
# Conole Results:
=begin 
sending oauth request...\n
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from sky.rb:34:in `<main>'
    2: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/oauth2-2.0.9/lib/oauth2/strategy/auth_code.rb:37:in `get_token'
    1: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/oauth2-2.0.9/lib/oauth2/client.rb:183:in `get_token'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/oauth2-2.0.9/lib/oauth2/client.rb:139:in `request': <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> (OAuth2::Error)
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>403 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method that was used for this request. The distribution supports only cachable requests.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: dNQrK3swhO2WYrEYt8xr38eCDdeBk6Q9Nql0I4t8fY3oXeyDAuu-bQ==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
=end
```

I tried varying the site_path because pointing to the root at blackbaud.com didn't match their documentation.  Potentially my redirect_uri might be the issue as it doesn't handle callbacks right now; Ruby catches the route and responds with a the message "success" in a JSON string.

I'm using Sinatra for routing like so:

```
get '/bb_oac'  do 
  JSON.generate('success').to_s
end
```

I was expecting to get a token from Blackbaud